# How to remove the character before the pattern found? (Unix)

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a variable:

```
$var="-- ---comment- --
      abcd;"
```

I want to remove every character that is between "--" comment "--"

Expected output:

```
$var="abcd;"
```

What I am trying in **test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
var="----comment---
     abcd;"
test=$(sed 's/^--.*--/' $var)
echo $test
```

It is not working. I get the following error:

> command not found

Comment: What about the newline and spaces after the last `--` ?

Comment: The title says "reading a file", but the question is about reading from a variable. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
$ cat foo.sh
var="----comment---                                                                                                          
     abcd;"
echo "$var"            # this outputs the original var
echo "${var/--*  /}"   # this output replacing everything between -- and "  "
$ bash foo.sh
----comment---
     abcd;
abcd;
```

You can set the output to a variable by

```
$ var="${var/--*  /}"
```

Comment: That won't give the correct output for the input given in the question

Comment: Oh, it changed.

Comment: And what comes to the OP, expected output doesn't seem to match the written requirement.

Comment: I know I asked in a comment on the question as it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Trying to replace the pattern that you don't expect in output with nothing, something like this

```
test=$(echo $var | sed 's/^--.*--//g')
```

Should work.